# How to get data from mysql and display them in a form using ajax

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I've created a form that I want to be automatically filled (the first_name and last_name fields to be automatically filled) with data from mysql when the user_id is entered. I've used ajax to do it and those data (I mean the first_name and last_name referring to the user_id input) are perfectly got from the database but I'm not getting them back in that form just because the XMLHttpRequest.response is sending back the entire "form.ejs" codes instead of sending those data.
I'm just a beginner in nodejs, Could you help me solve it, please?
Take a look to these portions of my codes :

form.ejs

```html
<label for = "user_id">User Id:</label>
<input type='text' name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user id" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">

<label for = "first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder='First Name' value="">

<label>Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder='Last Name' value="">
```

the form.ejs is linked to the below script ajax.js

ajax.js

```js
function GetDetail(str) {
if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (results) {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = myObj[0];
        document.getElementById("last_name").value =myObj[1];
         }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/?user_id=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
     }
}
```

"this.responseText" sends back the entire "form.ejs" scripts but I want it to send back the data (first_name and last_name) taken in the database instead.

Here is the server side
Server.js

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var userid = req.query.user_id;
    var data = [];
    if (userid !== ""){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user_id = ?",[userid], function (err, results, fields) {
            if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var a = results[i].first_name; 
                    var b = results[i].last_name;
                }
            }
            data.push(a, b);
            var obj = JSON.stringify(data);
            res.render("form", {obj:obj});
        });
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to return your response as `JSON` rather than using the `res.render` method that renders a view - [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json)

Comment: goto1 Try to review my question now I've just modified something in the server.js

Answer (score 0):

You are use EJS incorrectly. EJS is a templating engine, so what you are doing is returning the 'form' ejs not the JSON itself.

This leaves you with two options.

1)Create an API route to return just the JSON
2)Return your query to EJS and have it render it

Personally, unless there is a reason to do this via ajax I would just render it as part of EJS

To render it in ejs what you want to do is this

Node

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var userid = req.query.user_id;
    var data = [];
    if (userid !== ""){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user_id = ?",[userid], function (err, results, fields) {
            if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            } else {
                //replace ejstemplate with ejs to render
                res.render('ejstemplate', {
                                //results will be accessable in the template 
                                results: results
                            })
                
                }
        });
```

So basically what we have done is take the response from the query and have passes it to a variable that EJS can use. NOTE: I don't use mysql so how it returns the response may be different, in postgres is put the response in a 'rows' object so console that out to get what you need, but for PG the response would be results.rows (this is a JSON object)

Then on your EJS template you can access the response like

```
<%-results[0].first_name%>
```

You can also loop over items if need by as well. EJS, as noted is a template language so it allows you to pass variables etc to the page and EJS will render it on the server not the client. Again, this is usually the better option unless you need to do it via XHR...

On the flip side if you do need to use XHR then the response would be different, and as noted would be something like

```
 res.json(results);
```

This would return the results in JSON and from there you can do what you need on the client side.

Comment: Proxim0, if I launch the server I've to get back the form (form.ejs) which has 3 fields, the first for the user id, the second for the firstname and the last for lastname and when the first is filled (with the user id), I want the two remaining fields to be filled automatically  (without refreshing the page) with data from mysql referring to user id input

Comment: This will depending on how you want to do it, but having a dynamic form usually is done via an XHR call, where you request the dropdown data based on user selection ( if the datset is small enough you could just bring it over on the initial request and select based off an inmemory data store via the client ) If doing it via XHR then you would create a handler for onChange on the dropdown, this would then trigger you XHR request to your API with the data and would process and inject into the dom